# Como realizar um QuerySet retornando a maior data com Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

Estou tentando realizar um QuerySet utilizando Django, quero retornar as datas mais recentes presentes no banco de dados, junto com os outros campos, onde usei o `prefetch_related()`. Porém, o uso do `Max('data')` retorna todos os dados presentes.

Essa são as tabelas que estou trabalhando no models.py...

```
#models.py
    class TipoServicos(models.Model):
            servico = models.ForeignKey(Servicos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            nomeServ = models.CharField(max_length=50)
        
            def __str__(self):
                return self.nomeServ
            
        class Controle(models.Model):
            cliente = models.ForeignKey(Clientes, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            data = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
        
            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.data
        
            class Meta:
                get_latest_by = "data"
        
        class StatusServico(models.Model):
            controle = models.ForeignKey(Controle, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            tipo_servico = models.ForeignKey(TipoServicos, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
            status = models.CharField(max_length=10)
        
            def __str__(self):
                return '%s' % self.status
```

E a minha view onde faço os Querys...

```
#views.py
def integra(request, servico):
    clientes = Clientes.objects.all().order_by('nome')
    servico = Servicos.objects.filter(nomeServ__iexact=servico)
    controle = Controle.objects.prefetch_related('statusservico_set').annotate(Max('data'))
    context= {
        'clientes': clientes,
        'controles': controle,
    }
    return render(request, 'app/integra.html', context)
```

Para melhor visualização, esse é a pesquisa que realizei por SQL, onde retorna as últimas datas com o ID do cliente.

```
select max(data), app_controle.cliente_id from app_controle
inner join app_statusservico on
    app_statusservico.controle_id = app_controle.id
inner join app_tiposervicos on 
     app_tiposervicos.id = app_statusservico.tipo_servico_id
where
    app_tiposervicos.servico_id = 1
group by app_controle.cliente_id
```